# Inconsistent of adding and deleting data

Tags: spring, jsp, controller

I'm currently having inconsistent of adding and deleting data which happen randomly without any errors showing. The page will just keep loading forever until I stop my tomcat server. I can't identify where is the problem which is causing this inconsistency.

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "menu/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView orderPizzaForm(@ModelAttribute(value = "pizzaform") PizzaTO pizzaTO,
        @PathVariable String userId) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("pizzaform");
    List pizzaList = pizzaService.getListByUserId(userId);
    model.addObject("pizzaList", pizzaList);
    return model;

}

@RequestMapping(value = "menu/add/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView orderPizza(@ModelAttribute(value = "pizzaform") PizzaTO pizzaTO, @PathVariable String userId,
        BindingResult result) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("pizzaform");
    pizzaFormValidator.validate(pizzaTO, result);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        List pizzaList = pizzaService.getListByUserId(userId);
        model.addObject("pizzaList", pizzaList);
        return model;
    } else {
        pizzaTO.setUserId(userId);

        String[] data = pizzaTO.getPizzaSize().split("\\|");
        pizzaTO.setPizzaSize(data[0]);
        pizzaTO.setPizzaPrice(Double.parseDouble(data[1]));
        pizzaService.addPizza(pizzaTO);

        List pizzaList = pizzaService.getListByUserId(userId);
        model.addObject("pizzaList", pizzaList);
        return model;
    }

}

////////////////////////////// DELETE PIZZA //////////////////////////////

@RequestMapping(value = "menu/delete/{userId}/{pizzaId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editEmployee(@ModelAttribute(value = "pizzaform") PizzaTO pizzaTO, @PathVariable String pizzaId,
        @PathVariable("userId") String userId) {

    pizzaService.deletePizza(pizzaId);

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("pizzaform");
    List pizzaList = pizzaService.getListByUserId(userId);
    model.addObject("pizzaList", pizzaList);
    return model;

}
```

pizzaform.jsp

```
<body>
<div style="text-align: center">
    <form:form commandName="pizzaform"
        action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/menu/add/${userId}" method="POST">
        <form:hidden path="userId" value="${userId}" />
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td><label id="pizzaCrust">Choose a crust:</label></td>
                <td><form:radiobutton path="pizzaCrust" value="Hand Tossed" />Hand
                    Tossed <form:radiobutton path="pizzaCrust" value="Thin Crust" />Thin
                    Crust<form:errors
                            path="pizzaCrust" class="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label id="pizzaFlavour">Choose a flavour:</label></td>
                <td><form:radiobutton path="pizzaFlavour" value="Pepperoni" />Pepperoni
                    <form:radiobutton path="pizzaFlavour" value="BBQ Chicken" />BBQ
                    Chicken <form:radiobutton path="pizzaFlavour"
                        value="Spicy Chicken" />Spicy Chicken<form:errors
                            path="pizzaFlavour" class="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label id="pizzaSize">Choose a size:</label></td>
                <td><form:radiobutton path="pizzaSize" value="10|23.80" />10 inch (Regular - 4 Pax)
                <form:radiobutton path="pizzaSize" value="12|30.80" />12 inch (Medium - 6 Pax) 
                <form:radiobutton path="pizzaSize" value="14|37.80" />14 inch (Large - 8 Pax)<form:errors
                            path="pizzaSize" class="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Add" />
                    <button type="button" name="back"
                        onclick="window.location='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/main'">Back</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
    <br> <br>
    <table border="1" bgcolor="black" width="600px" align="center">
        <tr
            style="background-color: white; color: black; text-align: center;"
            height="30px">
            <td><b>Crust</b></td>
            <td><b>Flavor</b></td>
            <td><b>Size (Inch)</b></td>
            <td><b>Price (S$)</b></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${pizzaList}" var="pizza">
            <tr
                style="background-color: white; color: black; text-align: center;"
                height="30px">
                <td><c:out value="${pizza.pizzaCrust}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${pizza.pizzaFlavour}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${pizza.pizzaSize}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${pizza.pizzaPrice}" /></td>
                <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/menu/delete/${userId}/${pizza.pizzaId}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: on which operation is it causing problem? add, delete or both?

Comment: ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("pizzaform"); What is "pizzaform". Where is this mapped to??

Comment: just edited my post. pizzaform is my jsp.

Comment: can you describe more about the problem? which url are you calling? or are you doing some form action in the browser?

Comment: When I add a new data is a form action which will post to /menu/add/${userId} and when I delete a data is just a direct to /menu/delete/${userId}/${pizza.pizzaId}. So the problem I encounter is I can add or delete data and it will refresh the page with an updated list of data at the bottom of the page in a table. It is very random, that it will not refresh the page but the data is added or deleted, and the browser will just keep loading until I stop tomcat.

Comment: can you put a debug point or System.out.println at the end of each method(return statement) and check if code is reaching those lines? want to know if controller method execution has completed and started with view rendering or not